# VsCode's autocompletion not working on a new spring-boot project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, intellisense, intellicode

I'm starting a new maven spring boot project on VSCode (via spring initializr).
When I try to edit any java file I don't have any autocompletion or code verifications (I mean the errors showing when you're typing something wrong).

I installed the spring boot and the java extension packs as well as intellicode but it does not work.

I'm working behind a proxy but the http-proxy environment variables are correctly set (since the autocompletion works on other projects that are not spring-boot projects).

I've been stuck on this issue for some days now but it didn't find any solutions on the web.

Comment: this might be helpful: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot

Comment: I've been following these steps already but it doesnt work

Answer (score 7):

1. Try closing vscode and cleaning your workspace storage:

   - On linux: `$HOME/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage`
   - On mac: `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage`
   - On windows: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\workspaceStorage`
2. In case it did't help, if you have the [VScodeVim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) extension, try disabling it and restarting vscode. This might be helpful.